# Wrap paragraphs in paragraph tags in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, xml, xhtml, xsd

I am using the export as XML feature in Microsoft Excel, I have an XML Schema Definition like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <xs:element name="timeline">
      <xs:complexType>
         <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name="event" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                   <xs:all>
                      <xs:element name="date" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                      <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" />
                      <xs:element name="caption" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                      <xs:element name="image" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0" />
                   </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
             </xs:element>
         </xs:sequence>
         <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string" use="required" />
         <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:string" use="required" />
         <xs:attribute name="order" type="xs:int" />
         <xs:attribute name="color" type="xs:hexBinary" />
      </xs:complexType>
   </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

My table looks like so:

```
╔══════╦════════════════════╦════════════════════════╦═══════════╦════════════════╗
║ date ║ title              ║ caption                ║ reference ║ image          ║
╚══════╩════════════════════╩════════════════════════╩═══════════╩════════════════╝
│ 1915 │ Alex's Birthday    │ We ate cake.           │ rcn_02    │ rcn/rcn_02.png │
│      │                    │                        │           │                │
│      │                    │ He didn't like cake.   │           │                │
├──────┼────────────────────┼────────────────────────┼───────────┼────────────────┤
│ 1920 │ Alex starts school │ He didn't like school. │ rcn_03    │ rcn/rcn_03.png │
└──────┴────────────────────┴────────────────────────┴───────────┴────────────────┘
```

What I want to do is convert mutliline cells and wrap each section in a `<p>` element. So instead of the current output which is:

```
<event>
   <date>1915</date>
   <title>Alex's Birthday</title>
   <caption>We ate cake.

He didn't like cake.</caption>
   <image>rcn/rcn_02.png</image>
</event>
```

I want to get:

```
<event>
   <date>1915</date>
   <title>Alex's Birthday</title>
   <caption>
      <p>We ate cake.</p>
      <p>He didn't like cake.</p>
   </caption>
   <image>rcn/rcn_02.png</image>
</event>
```

Does anyone know how this is possible without manually inserting the tags into the text (I have many hundreds of rows)?

Comment: Is the issue with capturing the Line Feed and parsing it to `<p> </p>`? [Is this of any help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986297/line-break-in-xml)

Comment: @Raystafarian I could do this with JavaScript, It's just a waste of processing power (and slow) to do it at runtime and a less streamlined process than I'd like to add another stage in the build process to bootstrap it. Ideally I'd like to do it at the same stage as I convert the spreadsheet to XML. I would of course add a p element definition to my XSD

Comment: Yeah I've never used an XML map like this, I thought maybe the tagging structure would be similar to what you might be able to do within excel.

Comment: Is it possible to get a download link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that it is possible to parse and insert tags using the XML exporter. It would be a simple task to add paragraph tags around each caption cell, but the actual insertion of paragraph tags in the middle of the cell contents doesn't seem like something that the XML export feature can do on its own. There are, however, other workarounds for your data set, assuming it's only the "caption" column that requires the paragraph tags.

Utilizing a text editor capable of performing search and replace operations against carriage returns and tab indentations (Notepad++, TextWrangler, BBEdit, Microsoft Word), you would copy the entire column to a new blank document. Place a blank carriage return at the beginning and the end of your data set. Utilizing the following find and replace criteria, I was able to modify your example text to fit:

Find:`\n\n` Replace:`</p><p>`

Find:`\n`   Replace:`</p>\n<p>`

You would then take the newly formatted text and paste it back into your spreadsheet. The column should then transform from looking like this:
`╦════════════════════════╦
║ caption                ║
╩════════════════════════╩
│ We ate cake.           │
│                        │
│ He didn't like cake.   │
┼────────────────────────┼
│ He didn't like school. │
┴────────────────────────┴`

To looking like this:
`╦═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╦
║ caption                                           ║
╩═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╩
│ <p>"We ate cake.</p><p>He didn't like cake."</p>  │ 
┼───────────────────────────────────────────────────┼
│ <p>He didn't like school.</p>                     │
┴───────────────────────────────────────────────────┴`